# ASP.NET Core DI in a class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 project that references a "Data Access Layer" project of typ .NET Core Class Library.

The Data Access Layger needs connection string from the appsettings.json in the ASP.NET Core project.

I have created a simple container like this :

```
public class DatabaseConnectionString : IDatabaseConnectionString
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DatabaseConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public string ConnectionString {
        get { return _connectionString; }
        set {  }
    }
}
```

In the ASP.NET Core Startup.cs > ConfigureService I have this :

```
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseConnectionString>(p => new DatabaseConnectionString(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

I know that I can add the IDatabaseConnectionString to a constructor of a controller in ASP.NET to get the container. But How do I get it while in the class library? I dont want to pass it all the way down from the controller and just adding the IDatabaseConnectionString to the constructor of a class in the class library do not work.

I probably need a service where I can ask to create a object of a class and let the service fill in the constructor interfaces with the correct objects?

For example filling in the IDatabasConnectionString in this class :

```
public class UserFactory : FactoryBase
{
    private readonly IDatabaseConnectionString _iDatabaseConnectionString;

    public UserFactory(IDatabaseConnectionString connectionString)
    {
        _iDatabaseConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hopefully, the empty setter of `DatabaseConnectionString` is just a typo or something. Please, don't create an empty setter. If it is not supposed to be set, then remove the setter.

Comment: _"IDatabaseConnectionString to the constructor of a class in the class library do not work"_ Why not?

Comment: What did you mean by `I dont want to pass it all the way down from the controller`? What were you passing it through?

Comment: Thanks, the setter is fixed :)

Comment: @Jasen take a look at the UserFactory class, the IDatabaseConnectionString  will have to be filled in by the DI. The question is how I create the UserFactory with the DI?

Comment: @mason If I take the IDatabaseConnectionString in to the controller(entry level) then I will have to pass it all the way down to the DAL where it will be used. This could mean that it is passed through 5-10 methods that do not really care about it. I want to create the UserFactory in the DAL and get the DI to fill in the constructor interface or in some other way fetch the IDatabasConnectionString representing object.

Comment: If the DI system cant fill in the interface when creating the class in the DAL then maybe there is something like this that could provide the object for the given interface? 

IOC.Current.Get<IMyInterface>();

Comment: @Banshee But why would you need to take it in the controller and pass it through to 5-10 methods? Why wouldn't you just have your DAL depend on IDatabaseConnectionString itself, and let the IoC container resolve it?

Comment: @mason that is want I want but I can´t see how to get it to work? I know that I can get the IDataBaseConnectionString from the entry level in the controller with IoC but that is not want we want. Instead we want the IoC to provide the IDataBaseConnectionString for the DAL class when created. The problem is that I do not get how this is done? Just instansiate the DAL class will demand the IDataBaseConnectionString as inparameter in constructor so in some way the IoC needs to step in here and fill it in. service locator could have solved that part but that is "bad practice".

Comment: And now you've arrived at the crux of the problem. You are instantiating the DAL class. Don't! That's not your job. That's the job of your IoC container. If you ever invoke a constructor for a class that contains logic (not a model or DTO) then you're not following proper IoC. If you're invoking a constructor yourself, that means you've created a hard dependency on a specific implementation, rather than on an abstraction (interface). That video I linked you to explains it rather nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that I can add the IDatabaseConnectionString to a constructor of a controller in ASP.NET to get the container.

No, that's not needed and it would be wrong.

> just adding the IDatabaseConnectionString to the constructor of a class in the class library do not work.

It doesn't work because you need to create the service that will use the connection string *and* add it to the services container.

For example:

```
public class Repository: IRepository
{
    public Repository(IDatabaseConnectionString databaseConnectionString)
    {
        _databaseConnectionString = databaseConnectionString;
    }
}

public class ServiceThatRequiresDatabase : IServiceThatRequiresDatabase
{
    public ServiceThatRequiresDatabase(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}

// ...
services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
services.AddScoped<IServiceThatRequiresDatabase, ServiceThatRequiresDatabase>();


public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(IServiceThatRequiresDatabase service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

---

By the way, as @YeldarKurmangaliyev said, your DatabaseConnectionString should be like this if you want to make it read-only:

```
public class DatabaseConnectionString : IDatabaseConnectionString
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; }

    public DatabaseConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the HomeController  was no controller and just a regular class how would I created it and let the injection system inject the ServiceThatRequiresDatabase?

Comment: @Banshee Well, some code consumes that class, doesn't it? That code is normally a Controller since that's the normal way into an application. What scenario are you dealing with?

Comment: @Banshee Read this article, there is a good explanation for your problem: https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/

Comment: A Controller might be the starting point of the call but its down in the DAL where the connectionstring is needed. I dont want to pass the connectionstring through say 5-10 methods that do not really use the connectionstring. I want to be able to create a class in the DAL that will use the DI to fill in the interface in the constructor based on the service register(in this case probably a singelton). Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: @Banshee You need to register the classes in the container (`sevices.Add...`) and inject the connection string in the class that actually uses it. You aren't using Entity Framework, are you? Because if you are, then this isn't the correct way

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No, I was thinking of using dapper in the DAL thats why I need the connectionstring.

Yes I get that I need to register what class/object that will represent a given interface with the service. The problem is to create the class that got the interface in its constructor(down in the DAL) and get the DI to provide the register object. This without passing the connection string all the way down from the ASP.NET Core project through several methods.

Comment: In some project I have seen something like this : IOC.Current.Get<IMyInterface>(); is this possible with the ASP.NET Core DI?

Comment: @Banshee This is called service locator pattern and it is considered as bad practice http://www.stefanoricciardi.com/2009/09/25/service-locator-pattern-in-csharpa-simple-example/. The better way is to use a constructor injection for your dependencies.

Comment: @KarelKral thanks, dident know that. Will have to read up some more. So the best practice is to let the entry point(for excample controller(MVC)) of a call provide all the injections that will be used in the chain and then pass them through all methods even if they are only used at the bottom? 

Would that not leave a lot of clutter code that are not really used untill the end of the "chain"?

Comment: @Banshee No, you didn't get Karel's point completely. Imagine that `ServiceThatRequiresDatabase` is the class where you are using Dapper in my example above. That's the only class that requires the connection string so it's the only class that requests it.

Comment: @Banshee Hope that my updated example makes more sense

Comment: @Banshee Only the class that actually needs an IDatabaseConnectionString should ask for it. That's part of the beauty of Dependency Injection. Your controller shouldn't need to help the DAL obtain a connection string. All it should do is depend on the DAL (by interface, not concrete type). Creating the DAL and satisfying its dependencies is the job of the IoC container, not the controller. I highly suggest you watch [this entire video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) so that you can truly understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks, I will have too look at that video, there is clearly something important that Im missing here. I should not provide the dbConnectionString as a injection in the entrypoint(controller). Its only the DAL class that should have it in its constructor as a dependency. But Im not clear on how this DAL class is created? I can´t just instansiate it, it will demand a injection with the constructor so the IoC needs to step in here in some way. I thought that the Service locator pattern would be the right way but its not.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Banshee You are welcome. Just take a detailed look at my updated code, it should clear things up, all classes are instantiated by the DI container

Comment: About the example, say that the HomeController calls Method 1 and then Method 2, both in the Business Logic Layger(Class lib). Then Method2 calls Method 3 in Data Access Layger(Class lib). Its only Method 3 that will need the connection and I do not want to pass it through HomeController, Method 1 and Method 2. 

I should probably add the connectionString interface to the constructor of the class that holds Method 3. But I do still not get how this class will be created? If I just try to instantiate it will demand a injection/interface.And I do not want to inject it in to the HomeController.

Comment: @Banshee Again, take a deep look at my example. It doesn't matter who needs the dependency. The client (class that calls Method3, let's say Class2) asks for *the dependency* of the class that holds Method3 in the library (I'll call it Class3). Class3 then asks for *the dependency* of the ConnectionString. Finally, HomeController asks for *the dependency* of Class2

Comment: I have the same exact problem as @Banshee and I don't understand how to prevent circular references problem.
I have a library class with 3 classes (Connection, Command, Parameter). 
I have a DAL whose services use that library to connect to the Database and realise commands. To get the connection, the DAL has to provide the connectionString. 
The Asp.Net Core client uses the DAL so how could I inject the connectionString from the Asp.Net Core startup configuration into the DAL without having a circular reference problem?

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between controller and class from a class library. You need to

1. Define a class in a class library and inject `IDatabaseConnectionString` into it. Your `UserFactory` is the right way.
2. register the `UserFactory` for DI

   ```
   serviceCollection.AddScoped<IUserFactory, UserFactory>();
   ```
3. Resolve the UserFactory by the DI. For example, use the UserFactory as the constructor parameter in some controller. Everything is connected by DI automatically.

   ```
   public MyController(IUserFactory userFactory)
   {
       _userFactory = myUserFactory;
   }
   ```

[Here](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) is the good explanation for understanding **Composition root**.

Comment: How do I instantiate the MyController class in your example?

Comment: `MyController` must be created by DI. So it must be registered for DI and just resolve it. The principle is the same. If `MyController` is Asp.Net controller class, then is registered automatically.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at your link.