# ASP.NET Core 3.1 get connection string in class library

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am crazy confused. I refactored my solution into two projects; a web and a DAL.  I am trying to follow the principles of DI, but I don't know how to get my connection to the DAL.

Here is what I have so far:

In web project:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // connection string
    var connectionString = new ConnectionString(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionstringfromappsettings"));

    services.AddSingleton(connectionString);
    ...
}
```

Class in web project to get value

```
public sealed class ConnectionString
{
    public ConnectionString(string value) => Value = value;
    public string Value { get; }
}
```

Class in DAL repo that I'm not sure how to get configuration:

```
public class ContactRepo : IContactRepository
{
    private readonly ConnectionString _connectionString;

    public ContactRepo(ConnectionString connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    ...
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Does this solution not work? What’s not working? It looks fine to me. You are registering the dependency with your DI container and injecting it where you need it. As long as the `ContactRepo` is also constructed via DI, you should get the value there.

Comment: The class ConnectionString class  lives in the WWW project with the appsettings.     The DAL doesn't recognize this class in the constructor of the repository.  Do I need to move it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are mapping your configuration to ConnectionString object located on your main Web app(which you called WWW project). You have a dependency from Web project to DAL class library as expected. you can not call the classes in Main app from DAL project. You may locate your ConnectionString at DAL project or some another layer which both projects have dependency towards. Also, you can directly call Configuration.GetSection(..)... when Configuration is the injected instance of IConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the class ConnectionString in the WWW project.

My fault:
This post helped me walk it though a bit.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54774994/asp-net-core-di-in-a-class-library)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should research Inversion Of Control(IOC) on google. For more deep info you should look Castle Windsor and Ninject packages.